Replace Azure Front door with API Management
At the moment we are using azure front door for networking and exposing the service to internet. Now we want to use just the API Management to provide the service to the clients and remove Front Door entirely. My questions are:
1. Is it possible to use just API Management to provide service maintaining security?
2. How can this be achieved?
So far I tried to create an api management using swagger and checked for access and api testing. All the service is on azure and under different resource group. the Front Door and API Management.

Look at setting an API policy.  From there you can maintain a firewall whitelist and possibly achieve your security goals.

Yes, look into how APIM can be integrated into VNET: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet The goal would be to put APIM into VNET in external mode such that it can still receive traffic from outside and route it into backend APIs inside VNET.
Mind that feature set and capabilities of Azure Front Door and Azure API Management are quite different and services are not interchangeable in general case.
